# Polling for changes to database and append new changes to the view in Rails using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm having some trouble appending content from the database to the view when new content is added to a specific table. Currently, every number of minutes the database is updated with new content by a cron job.

The goal in the end is to have the page displaying this content being added to the database to display the latest content without refreshing the page. The only way I can think about how this could be done is with AJAX. I have looked into Railscast 229 where they talk about how to do this but it wasn't making a lot of sense.

If seeing code samples will help then I can provide some of that as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

With a typical multi process rails setup polling ist your best option.

There also 2 alternatives. Websockets and Server Sent Events which can be used with multithreaded or evented (NIO) deploys.

In both cases there is long open connection between the browser client and the servier, through which the server can publish updates, the client subscribes to. Server Sent Events are actually pretty easy in rails. Checkout [Mini-chat with Rails and Server-Sent Events](http://www.sitepoint.com/mini-chat-rails-server-sent-events/)

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382899/rails-consumption-of-external-api-requiring-staggered-consumption) answer about different types of concurrency models